# vuejs inline onclick event for multiple

Tags: vue.js

So I have a vuejs inline event that works great for one, but I want to expand it. Right now it checks for a specific property and the event changes based on what property is there. Issue is, I prefer to keep this inline instead of moving it all to a method in the model. So i guess this would become a big tenerary operation? So it checks to see if oil is there, if so it will trigger the click method. If its food, it will trigger that click2 method and anything else will trigger the click3 method. My goal is to keep this inline.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "food", done: false },
      { text: "pasta", done: false },
      { text: "oil", done: true },
      { text: "cheese", done: true }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
  click:function(){
  alert ("one clicked");
  },
   click2:function(){
  alert ("two clicked");
  },
   click3:function(){
  alert ("anything else");
  }
    
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="todos.text==='tractor'?click(todos): todos.text==='jack'?click2(todos):click(todos)">
    click me
  </button>

</div>
```

Comment: where did you define **`todo`**?

Comment: Replace `|` with `:` in your ternary expression and it should work.

Comment: @IgorMoraru doesnt work if i do

Answer (score 0):

Just send the todo as a param and do the logic there:

```
// template
  <button v-on:click="click(todo)">
```

Then inside your component script:

```
methods: {
  click(todo){
    switch (todo.text){

     case 'oil':
       //Call a method or do logic here
       this.handleOilTodo();
       break;

       ....
```